# daily count and weekly count mongo data

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

.

Below is code used, using below query to get the daily unique records, how can I write a query for getting unique weekly records, also if possible only for 5 days unique count  in a week(Mon-Friday), how can we modify daily unique records counts query below  to  get weekly unique records count.

```
 db.custom.aggregate([
        {
                $match: {
                    "loginLogoutTime": {
                        "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                        "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: {Dates: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime"}}, Role: "$customROLE"},
                    uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"}
                }
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    "_id": NumberInt(0),
                    "Dates": "$_id.Dates",
                    "ROLE": "$_id.Role",
                    "TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}
                }
            }
        ])
    
    the output looks from above query:
     "Dates" : "2020-04-10",
        "ROLE" : "PFS_CW_TECH",
        "TOTALUSERS" : 374
        
        
         "Dates" : "2020-06-16",
        "ROLE" : "CFS_CW_TECH",
        "TOTALUSERS" : 277
```

Also Schema object collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 55,
    "id" : "dm4955",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.lh.com",
    "Role" : "CFS_CW_TECH",
    "event" : "TIMEOUT",
    "timeoutTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:33:13.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T18:33:14.663Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 38,
    "attUid" : "mo441b",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.lh.com",
    "Role" : "PFS_CW_TECH",
    "event" : "LOGIN",
    "loginLogoutTime" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:34.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:35.220Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

from above query getting daily unique records counts  for role names:
ex:
For daily unique count of records from above  query output like for daily records
for a week (Mond-fri) , how to modify query to get unique counts for  groupby rolenames.

```
"Dates" : "2020-04-10",
    "ROLE" : "PFS_CW_TECH",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 374
    
    "Dates" : "2020-04-12",
    "ROLE" : "PFS_CW_TECH",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 384
                                                                                                                                               "Dates" : "2020-06-16",
    "ROLE" : "CFS_CW_TECH",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 277
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below Aggregate query to fetch unique weekly records.

```
db.custom.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {Dates: {$week: "$start_date"}, Role: "$role"},
            uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": NumberInt(0),
            "WeekNumber": "$_id.Dates",
            "ROLE": "$_id.Role",
            "TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}
        }
    }
])
```

> The con in this method is that you will get the week number of the grouped date instead of full-fledged date, although you can do a projection and get the actual date in the `$group` stage.

In order to get the counts of working days of a week (i.e., Monday - Friday), you can use the below Aggregate Query.

```
db.custom.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")
            },
            "$expr": {
                "$and": [
                    {"$gt": [{"$dayOfWeek": "$start_date"}, 1]},
                    {"$lt": [{"$dayOfWeek": "$start_date"}, 7]}
                ]
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {Dates: {$week: "$start_date"}, Role: "$role"},
            uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": NumberInt(0),
            "WeekNumber": "$_id.Dates",
            "ROLE": "$_id.Role",
            "TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}
        }
    }
])
```

**UPDATE:**
The below Aggregation will work as per your requirement discussed in the comment section.

```
db.custom.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-01-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-09-11T14:32:00.000-0400")
            },
            "$expr": {
                "$and": [
                    {"$gt": [{"$dayOfWeek": "$loginLogoutTime"}, 1]},
                    {"$lt": [{"$dayOfWeek": "$loginLogoutTime"}, 7]}
                ]
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "Date": { 
                    $dateToString: { 
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        date: "$loginLogoutTime" 
                    } 
                }, 
                "weekNumber": {
                    $dateToString: { 
                        format: "%Y-%m", 
                        date: "$loginLogoutTime" 
                    } 
                }, 
                "role": "$customROLE",
            },
            uniqueDayCount: {"$addToSet": "$_id"},
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {"weekNumber": "$_id.weekNumber", Role: "$_id.role"},
            "TOTALUSERS": {$sum: {$size: "$uniqueDayCount"}},
        }
    },
], { allowDiskUse: true})
```

I would also recommend to index `loginLogoutTime` for optimal query performance

```
db.custom.createIndex({"loginLogoutTime": 1})
```

> Note: I haven't tested the query result, so report in case of any errors

Comment: Thanks experts, Is this Matching dates will not effect is it: $match: {
            "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")

Comment: I am not quite sure what you asked for in comment, but if you are asking if the `$match` date ranges will affect your query result, then for sure it will. That is, the output of the query will be all the MongoDB records of `loginLogoutTime` key within the specified date ranges (Between `$gte` and `$lt`). If you want your query result for all the date rangex, just remove the `$gte` and `$lt` conditions in `$match` stage

Comment: We are using collection: /* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 55,
    "id" : "dm4955",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.lh.com",
    "Role" : "PFS_CW_TECH",
    "event" : "TIMEOUT",
    "timeoutTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:33:13.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T18:33:14.663Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: /* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 38,
    "attUid" : "mo441b",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.lh.com",
    "Role" : "CFS_CW_TECH",
    "event" : "LOGIN",
    "loginLogoutTime" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:34.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:35.220Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: Can you post your expected output based on the above sample records

Comment: from above query getting daily unique records counts for role names: ex: For daily unique count of records from above query output like for daily records for a week (Mond-fri) , how to modify query to get unique counts for groupby rolenames.

Comment: "Dates" : "2020-04-10", "ROLE" : "PFS_CW_TECH", "TOTALUSERS" : 374 "Dates" : "2020-04-12",
"ROLE" : "PFS_CW_TECH",
"TOTALUSERS" : 384
                                                                                                                                           "Dates" : "2020-06-16",
"ROLE" : "CFS_CW_TECH",
"TOTALUSERS" : 277

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the counts weekly (from Monday to Friday) but with unique counts of users registered daily, For example: Monday: U1, U2 got registered, Tuesday: U2, U3 got registered. So, the report will be: Week: 7, ROLE: "CFS_CW_TECH" TOTALUSERS: 3       Or do you want the output to be of daily counts except for weekends? For Example: Date: "2020-06-21" (Friday), ROLE: "CFS_CW_TECH" TOTALUSERS: 1 (Date: "2020-06-22" -> Saturday wont be included in the report. Help me understand so that I can send you the query which works for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216560/discussion-between-bha-25-and-hhharsha36).

Comment: HI Experts, yes we need same output: the counts weekly (from Monday to Friday) but with unique counts of users registered daily, For example: Monday: U1, U2 got registered, Tuesday: U2, U3 got registered. So, the report will be: Week: 7, ROLE: "CFS_CW_TECH" TOTALUSERS: 3